# apt-get update error failed to fetch

Tags: apt, updates

I have a problem with `apt-get update`.  When I try to use it, I have "failed to fetch" problem.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Cannot initiate the connection to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.92.152). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

I tried to choose the best server and had a "No suitable download server was found". Internet on.

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you have to use a proxy server? What about opening the URLs in a web browers...

Comment: URLs opening in web browsers and i do not use any proxy servers. Due to reputation, i can not provide full imformation, cause i can't post more than 2 URLs in post.

Answer (score 0):

http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en and http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_US doesn't exist in the server and can be ignored without problems.

Comment: there's many other URL's Ubuntu failed to fetch, i can't provide full information due my reputation. List don't even fit terminal window.

Comment: You can upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and insert your link. Also, if you indent the links the system allows you to post them.

Comment: TY for tips, i will use it if i have a future troubles. Due ubuntu was installed on my workplace my supervisor called a specialist in my absence. I don't know that he did, but now my system works properly. Thanks for the reputation, and thanks for trying to help me. Hope system will work well for me.